# fixed columns of an table inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having table inside a div of height 150 px.
The first and last column are fixed through css and jQuery.

but when table row increases and crosses the div height 150px then fixed columns aapears above the div and they are not scrolling vertically with table rows.

I want first and last columns are fixed and all other columns can be visible by use of horizontal scroll bar.

Thanks in Advance

Script is

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".firstFixedColumn").css('left',$(".mainTable").offset().left);
        $(".lastFixedColumn").css('left',$("#mainDiv").width() + $(".mainTable").offset().left -150);
    });
```

css is

```
.custom_width_200px {
    width: 150px;
}
.firstFixedColumn {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: white;
}
.afterFirstColumn {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.lastFixedColumn {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    background-color: white;
}
.beforeLastColumn {
    position: relative;
    right: 150px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.mainTable {
    text-align: center;
}
.mainTable th.notFirst, .mainTable td.notFirst {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
}
```

and Html is

```
 <body>
    <div id="mainDiv" style="width:75%;overflow:auto;position:relative;display:inline-block;height:150px;">
      <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mainTable" width="100%" id="programhierachy" style="table-layout:fixed;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="firstFixedColumn fixedThtdproject account_text   custom_width_200px"> <span style="padding-left:20px !important;">First Heading</span><!--<a class="custom_arrowLeft" onclick="SetColumns('PREV')"> </a>--></th>
            <th class="notFirst afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum </th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Lorem ipsum dolor</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">BeforeLast</th>
            <th class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px">Last Heading</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td class="fixedThtdproject account_level account_ll custom_width_200px firstFixedColumn">Lorem ipsum </td>
            <td class="notFirst  afterFirstColumn custom_width_200px" >11111111111</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px" >2222222</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">33333</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4444444</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">1</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">4</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">Y</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">before last</td>
            <td class="notFirst  custom_width_200px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="lastFixedColumn custom_width_200px"><span class="redbox_inner">last column</span></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting `position: absolute` to the first and the last columns.

See this example:

```css
body { font:16px Calibri;}
table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
td {
  margin:0;
  border:3px solid grey; 
  border-top-width:0px; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div { 
  width: 600px; 
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  margin-left:5em; 
  overflow-y:visible;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
.first{
  position:absolute; 
  width:5em; 
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  border-right: 0px none black; 
  border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
}
.last{
  position:absolute; 
  width:5em; 
  right:0;
  top:auto;
  border-right: 0px none black; 
  border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
  background: white;
}
.first:before {content: 'Row ';}
.long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td class="first">1</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">2</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">3</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">4</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">5</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">6</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">7</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">8</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="first">9</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="last">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hi  rahul thanks for replying but when I set height for the div (table parent) around 150px then  the fixed columns are comes out of the div. Please help me in that.

Comment: @SaurabhMahajan In that case, try applying `overflow-y: scroll` to the div.